# I am trying to write a method to delete a file from the internal storage in Android device and

Tags: android

```
imagedirectory = new File(path);
imagepool = imagedirectory.listFiles();
Uri targetdelete = Uri.fromFile(imagepool[photoindex]); //photoindex is integer 1
File filetodelete = new File(targetdelete);
boolean deleted = filetodelete.delete();
```

I am receiving an error in this line

```
File filetodelete = new File(targetdelete);
```

it says targetdelete must be a string object....  I thought it was valid to put Uri object as the agrument when initializing a File object?

Thanks once again, wonderful experts on stack overflow!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do deleted = imagepool[photoindex].delete();

Comment: Thank you, you just proved that I just won the "idiot of the month" award.

Comment: it was a very simple and perfect solution!!

Comment: You should mark this as answered by clicking the green arrow :)